# Multiple level argparse subparsers

Tags: python, argparse

I have multiple levels of subparsers within subparsers, but when I run the program with help flag, I see help messages and choices only for top level options. How can I see help for all suboptions, or for specific suboption in deeper level?

Comment: It would be helpful if you included the code you have that relates to the argument parsers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get the help for a subparser, use a command like `python prog.py cmd1 -h`.  To get the help for a sub-subparser, `python prog.py cmd1 cmd12 -h` should work.

There isn't a means, with the default help mechanism, to show the help for the main parser and all the subparsers (and sub-subparsers) with one command.  It just gets too complicated.

I'd suggest custom usage and description.  That includes titles and descriptions for the subparsers, etc.